# how to make redirect when the the login limit expires?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, session-timeout

on my page I use a lot of Jquery-ajax to some user action (sending messages in system, adding comments to articles etc.). This functionality is allow only for registered a logged users.

for example:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult AddArticleComment(Int64 idArticle, String articleComment)
{
  //process
}        
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#btnAddArticleComment").click(function () {
    showProgressBar();
    jQuery.ajax("/Articles/AddArticleComment",
                        { type: "POST",
                            data: { idArticle: $("#txtArticleId").val(), articleComment: $("#txtArticleComment").val() },
                            success: function (resultObj) {
                                hideProgressBar();
                                LoadArticles($("#txtArticleId").val());
                            },
                            error: function (xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                                hideProgressBar();
                                showInfoBox(false, "some error message");
                            },
                            async: false
                        });
        return false;
    });
};
```

In my *web.config* I set login timeout to 30 minutes. When a user writes a longer comment and the login limit expires, the application does not redirect to the login (eg: `http://localhost/Account/Logon?ReturnUrl....`).

How do I make a redirect in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this blog post out: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx

The idea behind it is to configure a custom module which will intercept 401 errors and instead of redirecting to the LogOn page and ending up with a 200 status code, it will simply propagate the 401 status code to the client. It will do this only if it is an AJAX request. This will allow you to simply subscribe to a global AJAX error handler and act accordingly if the status code is 401 which would mean that the user is not authenticated.